# How can I cancel a map once a condition has been met?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to map an array of Erbenisen over a map function and use another map function within this map function, which depending on whether the array contains an ID, shows me a corresponding icon.
The problem is that the function continues to work, even though the ID was found. But I want the map to stop when an ID is found

```
  {ergebnis.map((e, index) => (

  [...]
  <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              {gemerkt.map((ge) => {
                return ge.id_pdf == e.id ? (
                  <StarIcon
                    onClick={() => toggleStart(index, e.id)}
                    style={{ color: "#E69123", cursor: "pointer" }}
                  ></StarIcon>
                ) : (
                  <StarBorderIcon
                    onClick={() => toggleStart(index, e.id)}
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  />
                );
              })}
        </IconButton>
    [...]
  )
```

The result. I want only a filled Sstar if the ID is in the second array and not filled if not.
[image]

Comment: Generally speaking you can't stop `map` unless you throw an error. There is fundamental reason for this: `map` is what makes arrays to be Functors and to satisfy functor laws you can't change array length while mapping. You could use either `filter + map` combination or `reduce + some flag`

Comment: @Captai-N did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

What I can think is the use of `slice` in order to get the sub-array of gemerkt and "force" it by this way to stop rendering.

So instead of

```
{gemerkt.map((ge) => {
```

try this

```
{gemerkt.slice(0, gemerkt.findIndex(ge => ge.id_pdf == e.id) + 1).map((ge) => {
```